# How to pass controller data (php) to the content blocks of ContentBuilder?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

i've bought the latest ContentBuilder.js from innovastudio.
I've integrated it in my cms and is working fine.
Now i have created new static blocks this works fine also.
But now i try to make dynamic blocks with php data passed from the controller when the page loads but can't seems to make it work.
I know php loads before javascript .But i'm a little bit stuck.

Does someone already have worked with contentbuilder.js and could someone please guide me how to resolve this issue please?

I'm working in laravel 5.8 , i did getelementbyid with javascript and replace the value with the dynamic value .
This works but only for single rows and not collections.-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
       var DBaddress = '{{$settings[0]['address']}}';
       var DBnumber = '{{$settings[0]['number']}}';
       var DBpostalcode = '{{$settings[0]['postal_code']}}';
       var DBtown = '{{$settings[0]['town']}}';
       var DBtel = '{{$settings[0]['telephone']}}';
       var DBemail = '{{$settings[0]['email']}}';




        var obj = $.contentbuilder({
            container: '.container_edit',
            imageselect: 'admin/laravel-filemanager',
            cellFormat: '<div class="col-md-12"></div>',
            rowFormat: '<div class="row"></div>',
            framework: 'bootstrap',


        });

        $('#btnViewSnippets').on('click', function () {
            obj.viewSnippets();
        });

        $('#btnViewHtml').on('click', function () {
            obj.viewHtml();
        });

        /*$('#btnSave').on('click', function () {
            save(obj.html());
        });*/

       document.getElementById("address").innerHTML= DBaddress;
       document.getElementById("number").innerHTML= DBnumber;
       document.getElementById("postalcode").innerHTML= DBpostalcode;
       document.getElementById("town").innerHTML= DBtown;
       document.getElementById("tel").innerHTML= DBtel;
       document.getElementById("email").innerHTML= DBemail;

    });
</script>
```

Here the section where the page builder is set :

```
@section('content')
<div class="container_edit">
            {!! $page->contentBuilder !!}
        </div>
@if( basename(url()->current()) !== $page->slug)
        <div class="is-tool" style="position:fixed;width:210px;height:50px;border:none;top:250px;bottom:50px;left:auto;right:30px;text-align:right;display:block">
            <button id="btnViewSnippets" class="classic" style="width:70px;height:50px;">+ Add</button>
            <button id="btnViewHtml" class="classic" style="width:70px;height:50px;">HTML</button>
            <button id="btnSave" data-id="{{$editPageDetails[0]->uuid}}" class="classic" style="width:70px;height:50px;">SAVE</button>
        </div>
@endif

@endsection
```

This is how i could manage to make it work, but again this is for single rows. I would like to have the complete collection so i could create dynamic blocks

Comment: can you show your html ?

Comment: the html is generated true the contentbuilder.
/* Video */
  {
      'thumbnail': 'preview/element-video.png',
      'category': '120',
      'html':
    '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">' +
              '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/P5yHEKqx86U?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>' +
             '</div>'
  },

Once i create a page with the content builder and save it.
The html (layout) is saved to the database.
And retrieved on the page itself.

The problem is not the html, but how to pass the php to js

Comment: what is the blocs you have to loop for ?

Comment: it doesnt work to copy the block?

Let me explain.

For example i need to loop this block :

Image left text right, for each article in the database it needs to take the pic of the db row and the description also.

Now when i try to do this it just show my variable (because javascript loads after php)

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI
this is the contentbuilder i use https://innovastudio.com/content-builder.aspx
i know its hard to explain.
But the main thing is i want my php vars in the blocks so its dynamical and don't have to edit it once the page is set

Comment: Is there any laravel package available to use contantbuilderjs? The one I have found https://github.com/kikoseijo/laravel-contentbuilderjs is looking very old